# Convert point cloud from pointcloud2 (rosbag) to bin (KITTI)

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, bin, kitti

How can I convert a point cloud saved in rosbag, in format sensor_msgs/PointCloud2, to .bin files in KITTI format?

I know that it is possible to convert to .pcd (http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#pointcloud_to_pcd) so perhaps even a pcd to bin converter would be enough.

Is there any available tool to do this?

I've found [this](https://github.com/leofansq/Tools_RosBag2KITTI), but it needs ROS kinetic (legacy ROS version).

Answer (score 0):

A python script to do it:

```
  pc = pypcd.PointCloud.from_msg(msg)
  x = pc.pc_data['x']
  y = pc.pc_data['y']
  z = pc.pc_data['z']
  intensity = pc.pc_data['intensity']
  arr = np.zeros(x.shape[0] + y.shape[0] + z.shape[0] + intensity.shape[0], dtype=np.float32)
  arr[::4] = x
  arr[1::4] = y
  arr[2::4] = z
  arr[3::4] = intensity
  arr.astype('float32').tofile('filename.bin')
```

Where x,y,z and intensity are arrays for a single point cloud. It's not strictly needed to use pypcd. ([Source](https://github.com/PRBonn/lidar-bonnetal/issues/78))

Also this [conversion tool](https://github.com/leofansq/Tools_RosBag2KITTI) can actually be used without ROS, using another tool for the conversion to pcd file.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR ROS1 Noetic**

***use [ros_numpy](https://github.com/eric-wieser/ros_numpy) package (see imports)***

***After cloning ros_numpy from Github, fix line 244 of point_cloud2.py from:***

```
def get_xyz_points(cloud_array, remove_nans=True, dtype=np.float):
```

***to:***

```
def get_xyz_points(cloud_array, remove_nans=True, dtype=np.float32):
```

**Node for saving .bin from PointCloud2 topic**
(*also saves a .pcd using the .bin file, so you can verify it is packaging correctly. Make sure to remove this after verifying so it can run faster.*)

```html
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointField
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
from sensor_msgs import point_cloud2
from std_msgs.msg import Header
import sensor_msgs.point_cloud2 as pcl2
import numpy as np
import struct
import open3d as o3d

# Clone from https://github.com/eric-wieser/ros_numpy
import ros_numpy

def bin_to_pcd(binFileName):
    size_float = 4
    list_pcd = []
    with open(binFileName, "rb") as f:
        byte = f.read(size_float * 4)
        while byte:
            x, y, z, intensity = struct.unpack("ffff", byte)
            list_pcd.append([x, y, z])
            byte = f.read(size_float * 4)
    np_pcd = np.asarray(list_pcd)
    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np_pcd)
    return pcd

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo('Received a PointCloud2 message')
    
    pc = ros_numpy.numpify(data)

    print(pc.shape)
    points=np.zeros((pc.shape[0],pc.shape[1],4))
  
    points[:,:,0]=pc['x']
    points[:,:,1]=pc['y']
    points[:,:,2]=pc['z']
    points[:,:,3]=pc['intensity']

    # Add to
    p = np.array(points, dtype=np.float32)

    global pc_number
    pc_number += 1

    # Save files
    bin_file = f'/home/user/Desktop/bin/{pc_number}.bin'       # TODO: Replace with your desired folder for .bin files
    pcd_file = f'/home/donceykong/Desktop/pcd/{pc_number}.pcd' # TODO: Replace with your desired folder for .pcd files

    p.astype('float32').tofile(bin_file)
    pcd = bin_to_pcd(bin_file)

    o3d.io.write_point_cloud(pcd_file, pcd)

def listener():
    global pub
    global pc_number
    
    # Init pc number
    pc_number = 0
    
    rospy.init_node('pointcloud_to_bin_file', anonymous=True)

    # Subscribe to the input PointCloud2 topic
    input_cloud = 'ouster/points' # TODO: Change this to your pc topic
    rospy.Subscriber(input_cloud, PointCloud2, callback)

    # Create a publisher for the output PointCloud2 topic
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/output_cloud', PointCloud2, queue_size=10)

    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```